# Wordpress : Pagination display last query when using a shortcode that has a query

Tags: wordpress, pagination

My problem is that I'm using a shortcode to display content of a custom post, everything works fine except that, when I'm using this shortcode in an article, the pagination shows the other custom enties, instead of showing the other articles.

Here my code :

```
function tour_dates($concert_date) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'date' => '2013-08-22'
), $concert_date));

$cp_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'concerts', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'meta_key' => 'tourdate', 'meta_value' => $concert_date['date']) );
if( $cp_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($cp_query->have_posts()) {
        setup_postdata($cp_query->the_post());
        $id = get_the_ID();
        $custom = get_post_meta($id);
        return 'Les informations du concert : ' . $custom['tourdate'][0] . ' @ ' . $custom['tourcity'][0];
    }
}
else {
    echo 'No concert found on ' . $concert_date['date'];
}
wp_reset_query();

}
add_shortcode('concert', 'tour_dates');
```

I don't understand why is this showing the other custom entries...

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the pagination shows the other custom enties" what are "other custom enties"?

Comment: I meant that instead of displaying the other articles, the pagination was showing the other custom posts ('concerts' in my case).

I've fixed this by putting a wp_reset_postdata(); before the return, and it works !

Comment: then submit your fix and mark it as answer